# Nvidia GTX970 error code 43 on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

Suddenly when opening my computer one time only 1 screen worked (I have a dual monitor setup that was working for almost 6 months now) and the screen resolution was horrible.

I checked in the device manager and found that the graphics card has an error, and it was a (Code 43) error.
I've googled it and tried many things to try and fix it:

- Uninstalled the driver using DDU while on safe mode
- Rolled back to a previous driver version (from the latest 385.41 to 375.95)
- Reset windows 10 and lost all my programs
- Tried putting the card in the other PCIe slot on the motherboard

Computer specs:

- Intel Core i5 3570k
- Asus - P8Z77-V-LK motherboard
- Gigabyte G1 Gaming GeForce GTX 970

Comment: Check all connections to the GeForce card. If the card is under warranty, use it.